# Steps to make video call using csipsimple in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have downloaded CSipSimple video plugin from http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CSipSimpleVideoPlugin/ and imported code into android studio . Then I have run it . But it shows the error , `"Default Activity not found".`

Can anyone provide me steps to make video call

Answer (score 1):

1. Download code from http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CSipSimple
2. In CSipsimple, use "make" to build it(guide to build CSipSimle https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild).
3. Download CSipSimpleVideoPlugin.
4. Use "make VideoLibs" to build video plugin.
5. Import CSipSimpleVideoPlugin and CSipSimple into eclipse. then run them.
6. In CSipsimple's preferences form, you need to enable video. to do so, "video call button" is add to dial panel.

Comment: I did not find any VideoLibs file . How can I find that ?

Comment: 'VideoLibs' is not a file.'make VideoLibs' is a command to build video plugin in CSipSimple directory.I would suggest to read link given in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can make videocall button visible by :
commenting this line-
  //findViewById(R.id.dialButton).setEnabled(enabled);
in DialerCallBar.java class & setEnabled() method.